# Separate value in loop

Tags: php, sql, fpdf

Im trying to print data from database in loop using fpdf. So I have number of processes. And there are assigned number of people for each process. So first sql is to get processes:

```
$process=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `process` WHERE projectNo='$projectNo'");
if (!$process) {die('Invalid queryyyyy: ' . mysqli_error());}
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($process))
{
    $proc[] = $row["process"];
    $len = count($proc); // getting length of an array  
}
```

Then Im trying to print assigned people for each process:

```
for($y=0;$y<$len;$y++)
{   

    $result4 = getProcessLeader($projectNo,$proc[$y]);
        if (!$result4) {
            die('Invalid queryyyy: ' . mysqli_error($con));
        }   
        while($row4 = mysqli_fetch_array($result4))
        {  
            $procLeader = $row4['proc_leader'];
            $column_procLeader .= $procLeader." (leader), ";

        }   

    $result5 = getProcessChecker($projectNo,$proc[$y]);
        if (!$result5) {
            die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error($con));
        }   
        while($row5 = mysqli_fetch_array($result5))
        {  
            $procChecker = $row5['proc_checker'];
            $column_procChecker .= $procChecker." (checker), ";
        }

    $result6 = getProcessStaff($projectNo,$proc[$y]);
        if (!$result6) {
            die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error($con));
        }   
        while($row6 = mysqli_fetch_array($result6))
        {  
            $procStaff = $row6['proc_staff'];
            $column_procStaff .= $procStaff." (staff), ";
        }
    $pdf->Mach("Process Name: $proc[$y]","","", $column_procLeader, $column_procChecker, $column_procStaff);
}
```

So my expected output should be something like this:

```
Process A:
AHMAD (leader)
JOHN (checker)
ACOL (staff) 

Process B:
BOB (leader)
PETER (checker)
DON (staff)   

etc.
```

But What I get is:

```
Process A:
AHMAD (leader)
JOHN (checker)
ACOL (staff) 

Process B:
AHMAD (leader), BOB (leader)
JOHN (checker), PETER (checker)
ACOL (staff), DON (staff)
```

How can I assign names correctly?

Comment: I don't completely understand your process. But it seems that you are executing same query for 3 times for one project number. I think you can minimize the query by fetching all the process with `role` and order by project number and loop it for display...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `$column_procLeader = $column_procChecker = $column_procStaff = '';` line next to for loop, as below.

```
for($y=0;$y<$len;$y++)
{   
  $column_procLeader = $column_procChecker = $column_procStaff = '';
  .....
```